# git rebase is failed

Tags: git, github

I try to run this command:

```
 *1. GIT_TRACE=1 git rebase devel 
06:38:56.523607 git.c:600 trace: exec: 'git-rebase' 'devel' 
06:38:56.524199 run-command.c:350 trace: run_command: 'git-rebase' 'devel' 
06:38:56.589056 git.c:371 trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' '--parseopt' '--stuck-long' '--' 'devel' 
06:38:56.619374 git.c:371 trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' '--git-dir' 
06:38:56.645134 git.c:371 trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' '--git-path' 'objects' 
06:38:56.663010 git.c:371 trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' '--is-bare-repository' 
06:38:56.682832 git.c:371 trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' '--show-toplevel' 
06:38:56.726529 git.c:371 trace: built-in: git 'config' '--bool' 'rebase.stat' 
06:38:56.744416 git.c:371 trace: built-in: git 'config' '--bool' 'rebase.autostash' 
06:38:56.765932 git.c:371 trace: built-in: git 'config' '--bool' 'rebase.autosquash' 
06:38:56.782171 git.c:371 trace: built-in: git 'config' '--bool' 'commit.gpgsign' 
06:38:56.808309 git.c:371 trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' '--verify' 'devel^0' 
06:38:56.830865 git.c:371 trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' '--verify' 'devel^0' 
06:38:56.858060 git.c:371 trace: built-in: git 'symbolic-ref' '-q' 'HEAD' 
06:38:56.884341 git.c:371 trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' '--verify' 'HEAD' 
06:38:56.920231 git.c:371 trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' '--verify' 'HEAD' 
06:38:56.943794 git.c:371 trace: built-in: git 'update-index' '-q' '--ignore-submodules' '--refresh' 
06:38:57.013045 git.c:371 trace: built-in: git 'diff-files' '--quiet' '--ignore-submodules' 
06:38:57.081901 git.c:371 trace: built-in: git 'diff-index' '--cached' '--quiet' '--ignore-submodules' 'HEAD' '--' 
06:38:57.113575 git.c:371 trace: built-in: git 'merge-base' '65175047adbeb20879af932112ddc75902519846' '658e3871df5427b32403a75049516f80084eaea0' 
06:38:57.410044 git.c:371 trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' '--git-path' 'hooks/pre-rebase' First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it... 
06:38:57.448020 git.c:371 trace: built-in: git 'checkout' '-q' '65175047adbeb20879af932112ddc75902519846^0' 
06:39:01.770078 git.c:371 trace: built-in: git 'update-ref' 'ORIG_HEAD' '658e3871df5427b32403a75049516f80084eaea0' 
06:39:01.794553 git.c:371 trace: built-in: git 'format-patch' '-k' '--stdout' '--full-index' '--cherry-pick' '--right-only' '--src-prefix=a/' '--dst-prefix=b/' '--no-renames' '--no-cover-letter' '65175047adbeb20879af932112ddc75902519846...658e3871df5427b32403a75049516f80084eaea0' 
06:39:08.220488 git.c:371 trace: built-in: git 'am' '--rebasing' '--resolvemsg= When you have resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue". If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git rebase --skip" instead. To check out the original branch and stop rebasing, run "git rebase --abort". ' 
06:39:08.238487 run-command.c:350 trace: run_command: 'mailsplit' '-d4' '-o.git/rebase-apply' '-b' '--' 
06:39:08.239436 exec_cmd.c:116 trace: exec: 'git' 'mailsplit' '-d4' '-o.git/rebase-apply' '-b' '--' 
06:39:08.247412 git.c:371 trace: built-in: git 'mailsplit' '-d4' '-o.git/rebase-apply' '-b' '--' 
Applying: Fix for ansible/ansible-modules-core#1568 
Applying: Rewrite ansible-pull tests to use local repo. (#22821) 
Applying: cloudstack: fix pep8 for loadbalancer modules (#22822) 
Applying: Fix get_s3_connection (fixes #22317) (#22318) 
Applying: fixes return data structure (#22830) 
Applying: fixes exception raised from ansible-connection logging (#22836) 
Applying: allow systemd to 'just' reload 
Applying: removed deprecated config/env vars 
Applying: fixed name to unit 
Applying: fixed passwordstore lookup examples 
Applying: ported fix from ansible-core #5639 fatal: could not parse .git/rebase-apply/0012
```

------------------------------------------------------------------------*

and I got

> fatal: could not parse .git/rebase-apply/0012

Then I can show this:
 cat .git/rebase-apply/0012

```
From 3d09c94faeaa52075055f23744d8b52581c59bb2 Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
Evan Kaufman <evan@digitalflophouse.com>
---
 lib/ansible/modules/files/replace.py | 13 +++++++++++++
 1 file changed, 13 insertions(+)

diff --git a/lib/ansible/modules/files/replace.py b/lib/ansible/modules/files/replace.py
index 60d5500cfdc44c53bfc67706181cba732c1ee914..ff82ce5f0abb75745b3738a097c94a7f7fe6e480 100644
--- a/lib/ansible/modules/files/replace.py
+++ b/lib/ansible/modules/files/replace.py
@@ -52,6 +52,10 @@ options:
         U(http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).
         Uses multiline mode, which means C(^) and C($) match the beginning
         and end respectively of I(each line) of the file.
+      - Note that, as of ansible 2, short form tasks should have any escape
+        sequences backslash-escaped in order to prevent them being parsed
+        as string literal escapes. See the examples.
+
   replace:
     required: false
     description:
@@ -141,6 +145,15 @@ EXAMPLES = r"""
     regexp: '^(NameVirtualHost|Listen)\s+80\s*$'
     replace: '\1 127.0.0.1:8080'
     validate: '/usr/sbin/apache2ctl -f %s -t'
+
+- name: short form task (in ansible 2+) necessitates backslash-escaped sequences
+  replace: dest=/etc/hosts regexp='\\b(localhost)(\\d*)\\b' replace='\\1\\2.localdomain\\2 \\1\\2'
+
+- name: long form task does not
+  replace:
+    dest: /etc/hosts
+    regexp: '\b(localhost)(\d*)\b'
+    replace: '\1\2.localdomain\2 \1\2'
 """
```

### import os

2.11.0

Not sure how can I handle couldn't parse. git/rebase-apply/0012 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a similar issue recently (Oct. 2017) [in this thread](https://public-inbox.org/git/20171118010116.GA17169@starla/t/#m70d4bcbb5a5786574278faf00b90125be14850d1)

The first thing to test is to check if the issue persists with a Git 2.15.0 (or 2.15.1 released this morning)

The other workaround would be to rebase up to *before* that commit, then apply that commit manually, and finally rebase from after that commit.

As [torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47545273/git-rebase-is-failed/47545809#comment82049954_47545809):

> A third alternative is to run any of:
>
> - `git rebase -m` (uses the merge script, which uses **cherry-pick**),
> - `git rebase --keep-empty` (forces `git rebase--am` to use cherry-pick), or
> - `git rebase -i` (interactive rebase uses cherry-pick).

Comment: A third alternative is to run any of `git rebase -m` (uses the merge script, which uses cherry-pick), `git rebase --keep-empty` (forces `git rebase--am` to use cherry-pick), or `git rebase -i` (interactive rebase uses cherry-pick).

Comment: @torek Good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.